# Table View Controller powered by NSFetchedResultsController, the cell label has issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use `NSFetchedResultsController` in a Table View Controller, When I insert an entry by clicking the add button at right-top corner, the label in table view cell is a different size than expected.

But when I restart the App, the issue will disappear. What's happening?

[image]

Comment: 不好意思，我看不懂 the label in table view cell is bigger than it had owned. 有什么意思？

Comment: 字的大小不对， 重启后就对了， 这是为什么

Comment: I think this is happening because the data from the `NSFetchedResultsController` and the data being input from the "Add" button are being formatted differently.  Are you formatting the text within your code when you populate the Table View?